# How to use compareTo to arrange flights by descending order

Tags: java, hashmap, compareto

I am creating a flight controller application.  A bit of functionality that i want is to be able to tell the user what the next flight is according to a specific airline.  I have a hash map which stores strings and planes.  In my plane class i am implementing Comparable and i have the compareTo method.  Could anyone help me achieve using the compareTo method to arrange the planes in descending order to show the next flight.  I want to arrange the flights by the variable overdue.

**This is the case in the MainApp that i have to use the compareTo on**

```
switch (nextChoice) 
                    {
                    case 1:
                        airlineMap.printAirline("Aer Lingus");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        airlineMap.printAirline("Brittish Airways");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        airlineMap.printAirline("Eithad");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        airlineMap.printAirline("Iberia");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        airlineMap.printAirline("Quantas");
                        break;
```

I hope to add the descending order to a airline print: airlineMap.printAirline("Aer Lingus");

**Here is my Plane class:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Plane implements Comparable
{   
    private String flightNumber;
    public String airlineName;
    private double fuelRemaining;
    private int overdue;
    private int passengerNumber;
    private AIRPLANETYPE planeType;

    public enum AIRPLANETYPE
    {
        AIRBUS("1"), CORPORATE("2"), PRIVATE("3");

        private String planeName;

        private AIRPLANETYPE(String planeName)
        {
            this.planeName = planeName;
        }

        public String getPlaneName()
        {
            return this.planeName;
        }
    }

    public Plane(String flightNumber, String airlineName, double fuelRemaining, int overdue, int passengerNumber, AIRPLANETYPE planeType) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
        this.airlineName = airlineName;
        this.fuelRemaining = fuelRemaining;
        this.passengerNumber = passengerNumber;
        this.overdue = overdue;
        this.planeType = planeType;
    }


    public String getAirlineName() {
        return airlineName;
    }

    public void setAirlineName(String airlineName) {
        this.airlineName = airlineName;
    }


    public void setOverdue(int overdue) {
        this.overdue = overdue;
    }

    public int getOverdue(){
        return overdue;
    }

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public double getFuelRemaining() {
        return fuelRemaining;
    }

    public void setFuelRemaining(double fuelRemaining) {
        this.fuelRemaining = fuelRemaining;
    }

    public int getPassengerNumber() {
        return passengerNumber;
    }

    public void setPassengerNumber(int passengerNumber) {
        this.passengerNumber = passengerNumber;
    }

    public AIRPLANETYPE getPlaneType() {
        return planeType;
    }

    public void setPlaneType(AIRPLANETYPE planeType) {
        this.planeType = planeType;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        if((arg0 != null) && (arg0 instanceof Plane))
        {
            Plane p = (Plane) arg0;
            return (int)Math.ceil(this.overdue - p.getOverdue());
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Plane: flightNumber=" + flightNumber + "."
                + " airlineName=" + airlineName + "."
                + " fuelRemaining=" + fuelRemaining + " litres."
                + " overdue=" + overdue + " minutes."
                + " passengerNumber="+ passengerNumber + "."
                + " airplaneType=" + planeType + ".\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's nick picky, but I would probably try and calculate the over due value rather then having it "set".  The basic idea would be have a departure time/date instead, which you could then use to determine if the plane is over due or not and by how much

Comment: Unfortunatly it was requested that overdue be a double,  but a calculation function would still not be out of the question.  I would rather use the compareTo to learn the use of it but if all else fails thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `HashMap` is unordered, you have two ways of going about sorting your planes:

- Put them into a sorted container, or
- Put them into an `ArrayList<Plane>` or an array `Plane[]`, and sort that list or array

The first approach can be achieved with a `TreeSet<Plane>`: put your planes into the set, and iterate them in the "natural" order (i.e. the order consistent with their `compareTo` method).

The second approach requires copying the planes into a separate container or an array, and then using the `sort` method (or the `Arrays.sort` static method if it is an array) to order your planes in accordance with the order set by their `compareTo` implementation.

**EDIT :** (based on a comment) One way to deal with a problem of storing planes in a specific order inside a hash map is to make a hash map of tree sets, like this:

```
Map<String,TreeSet<Plane>> airlineMap = new HashMap<String,TreeSet<Plane>>();
```

Once you add the planes to each airline, they would be maintained in the order based on your `compareTo` implementation. with a `TreeSet<Plane>` in hand, you can easily find the next or the prior `Plane` by calling `higher` or `lower`.

You should use `Math.signum` rather than `Math.ceil` in your `compareTo` method.

Comment: Is there any way that i could just call the method, like airlineMap.print("Aer Lingus").compareTo();  Obviously this doesn't work.  But something reasonably similar.

Comment: @Pendo826 Take a look at the edit. You should be able to implement your `print` method simply by iterating the `TreeSet` stored at the key for the corresponding airline in the "natural" order, because the order will be based on your `compareTo` function.